# Responsive Grid of Squares in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

I want to create a grid of responsive images that are always squared in Bootstrap.

So far I got this: [Jsfiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/78tf3px2/1/)

This part forces the elements to be squared all the time:

```
.frontpage_square {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-bottom:100%;
}

.frontpage_square img {
    position:absolute;
}
```

The bigger square on the left and the nine smaller ones on the right are correct, but I can't figure out how I can spread the nine squares on the right over the full height. So basically they should take the whole height of the left, bigger square.

Comment: I can achieve it easily by doing some math. But why would you want such a messy grid system..?

Comment: Why is it messy? It is sth. like "1 featured element in bigger size and 9 normal elements in smaller size in a grid beside it". Nothing too crazy here or am I wrong?

Comment: Nothing wrong about it.. But the output contains too much padding and also the way you have achieved a square thumbnail `padding:100%` may not be the best.

Comment: For future readers using Bootstrap 4, [this question may be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49692456/bootstrap-grid-square-tiles-with-same-horizontal-vertical-gap/49692667#49692667)

Answer (score 6):

It is simple, you aren't arranging your divs properly. Make use of bootstrap by using the divs properly. Once that is done, you can make the column all same size by using [this S.O. question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height).

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rgsgdfsg/1/)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 panel">

            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <div class="frontpage_square">
                    <img src="" class="img img-responsive full-width" />
                </div>
            </a>    

    </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 panel">

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <div class="frontpage_square">
                    <img src="" class="img img-responsive full-width" />
                </div>
            </a>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-4">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <div class="frontpage_square">
                    <img src="" class="img img-responsive full-width" />
                </div>
            </a>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-4 ">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <div class="frontpage_square">
                    <img src="" class="img img-responsive full-width" />
                </div>
            </a>
       </div>  

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <div class="frontpage_square">
                    <img src="" class="img img-responsive full-width" />
                </div>
            </a>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-4 ">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <div class="frontpage_square">
                    <img src="" class="img img-responsive full-width" />
                </div>
            </a>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-4">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <div class="frontpage_square">
                    <img src="" class="img img-responsive full-width" />
                </div>
            </a>
       </div>  

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <div class="frontpage_square">
                    <img src="" class="img img-responsive full-width" />
                </div>
            </a>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-4">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <div class="frontpage_square">
                    <img src="" class="img img-responsive full-width" />
                </div>
            </a>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-4">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <div class="frontpage_square">
                    <img src="" class="img img-responsive full-width" />
                </div>
            </a>
       </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Okay, first thing I found out: used an old version of Bootstrap. Fixed that and used your method. But after a fair amount of googling I still don't know how I can give the right block of 9 squares the same height as the single big left square. As in your jsfiddle, the last row of the 9 squares always ends a few pixel higher than the big square. So it seems like they have a padding-bottom I don't want them to have...

Comment: shouldn't there be rows every 12 columns?

Comment: @niico not necessarily. it all depends on you and what you want to achieve at the end of the day.

Comment: thx. How would you do this if you want to put text in the squares (currently it makes the 'square' taller than it is wide if you add text to it) - I asked a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40445364/responsive-squares-with-background-image-content-in-bootstrap-3-grid

Comment: Would this answer change with bootstrap 4?